# Need explanation of behavior using .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to JS and JQuery behavior and trying to further expand my understanding of how `.each()` works and looping in JS/JQuery in general. I have a good understanding of PHP and `foreach()` loop and in my research I found `.each()` is a good way to iterate over an array and compare key/value 's. I am struggling however to understand the logic behind the following function I have written to iterate over a simple array and compare the values to an input from a text field.

I can see through testing that my value is only comparing the last value from the array with the input I have entered when I submit the `search` button. I am missing something simple I am sure.

Also, when I change my operator from `==` to `===` the results are not the same, *at least with the last value which is the only one that is seen in the comparison I have written ->* ***Peach*** . I always get a false return using the strict `===` operator. I know that the difference is in the `type` but this does not make sense to me as they are both string values, right? I am a bit confused and could use some explanation please.

***UPDATE:*** Code works after implementing answer into question. Changed the use of `this` to getting the value of the array and setting that to my iterated value check. Thank you to Khauri for a through explanation on the difference between `$.each()` and `.each()` and the use of `this`.

[image]

```js
var haystack = new Array("Orange", "Pear", "Apple", "Peach");
var $button = $("#search");
$("#array").append(haystack);
$($button).click(function() { // the search button is pressed
  var $needle = $("#needle").val(); // get value of input field
  $.each(haystack, function(index, value) { // iterate through the array "haystack", I also tried $(haystach).each(function(){

    var $value = value; // initially I had this set to this, that was my problem, cahnged to the use of the value and it works.
    var $result = $("#result"); // get the id to place result for ==    
    var $check = $("#check"); // get the id to place check comparison ==
   
    // When the last value is used in input #search, I get a match using the == comparison but not when using the strict comparison. Why? 
    if ($needle === $value) { // compare values using == true
      $check.text("Haystack: " + $value + " == " + "Needle: " + $needle).css("background-color", "#90ee90"); // output to #check if == true
      $result.text("Result found using '==' :" + $value).css("background-color", "#90ee90"); // output to #result if == true
    }
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}

div {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="display"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="array">Array: </span>
</div>
<div style="container">
  <input type="text" id="needle">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
</div>
<div>
  <span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="check"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="strictResult"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="checkStrict"></span>
</div>
```

**NOTE** Please explain your answer if you could. My reasoning behind this question is not for a working code per say but a useful logical explanation as to why `.each()` is not looping through each value from the array as I have it laid out. Thank you in advance for any knowledge you can share!

Comment: Do not confuse `.each()` with `$.each()`. The former is designed for a group of elements where as the latter is for Arrays and Objects.

Comment: @twisty thank you for your comment. I adjusted the code using `$.each(haystack, function(){` I am still getting the same result where only the last value is being compared in my if statement.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Running the snippit I only get a successful result when I enter the last value of the array-> `Peach`, if I run any of the other values there is no result. The log is showing up correctly and has been the entire time. However the comparison does not loop the if statement and display those values.

Comment: That's because you overwrite your previous text each iteration of the loop as opposed to appending to it or collecting all the failures at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few assumptions you're making when using jquery. 
The biggest here is that [`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) is not exactly the same as calling [`$(obj).each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).
The latter is used to loop over DOM elements while the former can be used for any generic array or object.

When you use the form `$(haystack).each` you are first converting haystack to a jQuery object. If you `console.log($(haystack))` you will get something that looks like this:

```js
object {
  "0": "Orange",
  "1": "Pear",
  "2": "Apple",
  "3": "Peach",
  "length": 4,
   // ... a bunch of functions jquery adds
}
```

jQuery also converts each item in your array to a jQuery object before setting it as the `this` context of your `.each` callback.

If you `console.log(this)` inside your loop you will see it similarly breaks your string into an object like so:

```js
{
  "0": "O",
  "1": "r",
  "2": "a",
  "3": "n",
  "4": "g",
  "5": "e"
}
```

Since this is an object, this object will never be strictly equal (`===`) to any string. 
But it may be loosely equal (`==`) to some string if the object has a `toString` method defined. If an object has a `toString` method, then calling things like adding it to another string, or doing a loose equality comparison might implicitly convert it back to a string.

Basically, do not us `this` to get the value as that is converted to a jQuery object. Instead, use the second argument passed to the callback of your `$.each`.

```js
$.each(haystack, function(index, value) {
  var $value = value;
```

Also, as an added problem, you are always overwriting the text in the `$check`, `$result`, etc on each iteration of your loop, when you probably meant to stop when you found a match or just append to the text. That's why it seems like only the last one is checked.

Depending on your wanted behavior you might find a good workaround for this, but in the following code snippet I've just opted to simplify your code a bit.

```js
var haystack = ["Orange", "Pear", "Apple", "Peach"];
var $button = $("#search");
var $display = $("#display");
var $needle = $("#needle");
var $result = $("#result"); // get the id to place result for ==
$("#array").append(haystack);
$($button).click(function() { // the search button is pressed
  var needle = $needle.val(); // get value of input field
  $display.text("Input: " + needle);
  // Reset result field
  $result.text("").css("background", "transparent");
  $.each(haystack, function(index, value) {
    // iterate through the array "haystack"
    console.log("Haystack: " + value + "\n\r" + "Needle: " + needle); // loging console for further testing 
    if (needle === value) {
      $result.text("Result found: " + value).css("background-color", "#90ee90"); // output to #result if == true
    }
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}

div {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="display"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="array">Array: </span>
</div>
<div style="container">
  <input type="text" id="needle">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
</div>
<div>
  <span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="check"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="strictResult"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="checkStrict"></span>
</div>
```

but you really don't need jQuery for this. Arrays in js have built in [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and perhaps more useful in this case, [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which can be used like so:

```js
var haystack = ["Orange", "Pear", "Apple", "Peach"];
var $button = $("#search");
var $display = $("#display");
var $needle = $("#needle");
var $result = $("#result"); // get the id to place result for ==
$("#array").append(haystack);
$($button).click(function() { // the search button is pressed
  var needle = $needle.val(); // get value of input field
  // Reset result field
  $result.text("").css("background", "transparent");
  $display.text("Input: " + needle);
  var res = haystack.find(value => value === needle);
  if(res) {
    $result.text("Result found: " + res).css("background-color", "#90ee90");
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}

div {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="display"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="array">Array: </span>
</div>
<div style="container">
  <input type="text" id="needle">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
</div>
<div>
  <span id="result"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="check"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="strictResult"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="checkStrict"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation I understand the use of `this` now and my problem in its use in my initial code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples using `$.each()` and various search techniques.

```js
$(function() {
  function report(trg, str, hex) {
    var p = $("<p>").html(str).css("backgroundColor", hex).appendTo(trg);
  }

  var haystack = new Array("Orange", "Pear", "Apple", "Peach");
  $("#array").append(haystack.join(", "));

  $("#search").click(function() {
    var term = $("#needle").val();
    $(".results").html("");
    $.each(haystack, function(k, v) {
      var $result = $(".results");
      var $display = $("#display");
      $display.text("Input: " + term);

      if (term == v) {
        report($result, term + " == " + v, "#90ee90");
        report($result, "Result found using '==': " + v, "#90ee90");
      } else {
        report($result, term + " == " + v, "#ff7f7f");
        report($result, "No result found in array using '=='", "#ff7f7f");
      }

      if (term === v) {
        report($result, term + " === " + v, "#90ee90");
        report($result, "Result found using '===': " + v, "#90ee90");
      } else {
        report($result, term + " === " + v, "#ff7f7f");
        report($result, "No result found in array using '==='", "#ff7f7f");
      }

      if (term.toLowerCase() == v.toLowerCase()) {
        report($result, term.toLowerCase() + " === " + v.toLowerCase(), "#90ee90");
        report($result, "Result found using '==' (Lower): " + v, "#90ee90");
      } else {
        report($result, term.toLowerCase() + " === " + v.toLowerCase(), "#ff7f7f");
        report($result, "No result found in array using '==' (Lower)", "#ff7f7f");
      }

      if (v.indexOf(term) != -1) {
        report($result, v + ".indexOf(" + term + ")", "#90ee90");
        report($result, "Result found using indexOf: " + v, "#90ee90");
      } else {
        report($result, v + ".indexOf(" + term + ")", "#ff7f7f");
        report($result, "No result found in array using indexOf", "#ff7f7f");
      }

      if (v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        report($result, v.toLowerCase() + ".indexOf(" + term.toLowerCase() + ")", "#90ee90");
        report($result, "Result found using indexOf (Lower): " + v, "#90ee90");
      } else {
        report($result, v.toLowerCase() + ".indexOf(" + term.toLowerCase() + ")", "#ff7f7f");
        report($result, "No result found in array using indexOf (Lower)", "#ff7f7f");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
}

div {
  margin: 2px;
}

.results p,
.checks p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="display"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span id="array">Array: </span>
</div>
<div style="container">
  <input type="text" id="needle">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="Search">
</div>
<div class="results">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to explain the code and your many different examples! Respect...